# Android: How to prevent any touch events from being passed from a view to the one underneath it?

Tags: android

Specifically using the code below, is there a way to modify it so that the activity under this newly created view does not receive any gestures?

```
View v1 = new View(this);    
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
 1000,
 50,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
 PixelFormat.OPAQUE);

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(v1, params);
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add an `onTouchEvent` method to the view with top position then return true. True will tell the event bubbling that the event was consumed therefore prevent event from bubbling to other views.

```
protected boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent me) {
    return true;
}
```

For `v1` you would do an import:

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
```

Then set the onTouchListener:

```
v1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Great solution, and perfectly fit for the question. It might be noted though, that it doesn't prevent the underlying views from receiving input from the physical keyboard (which means users can still fiddle with the pseudo-disabled components if they use a phone with physical cursor keys, like I do).

Answer (score 79):

#### From code

```
View v1 = new View(this);   
v1.setClickable(true);
v1.setFocusable(true);
```

OR

#### From xml

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My button"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

This will prevent touch and click events from being propagated to views that stay below your view.

Or if you inflate the View then to .xml add `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: Note this might have an adverse affect of the click's touch animation being passed to the view's first focusable element. In my case, I had a SeekBar as a child of the clickable view and pressing anywhere inside it would cause the SeekBar's ripple animation to start.

Comment: I think it is the best solution as it can be done directly from xml

Comment: this works. no need to create onTouchListener in Kotlin/Java

Answer (score 28):

You can do this too. You can set touch listener to child view and then in `onTouch()` event, you can block `intercept touch event` of parent — using this code that I copied from the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19311197/1 —

> ```
> View v = findViewById(R.id.sample_view); v.setOnTouchListener(new
> OnTouchListener() {
>     // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView
>     @Override
>     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
>     // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
>     v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
>     return false;
>     } });
> ```

Comment: This help me with recyclerview nested inside another recyclerview with same scroll direction and fast scroller cannot work. Call prent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true) inside fast scroller onTouch event solved the problem.

Answer (score 19):

You add a view like below, but make sure it is the last view you add to your xml. The last item in the xml is the item that lays on top of all the other views under it.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/blocking_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#AA666666"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

Comment: `clickable` is the important part here. But: Even if your layout that's on top of everything else (it can also be `include`d) is set to `match_parent`, it won't cover the toolbar, which means that buttons on the toolbar are still going to be clickable.

Comment: This is a working solution, the main thing is to set the highest ELEVATION for this blocker.

Answer (score 4):

all you need to do is just call

```
arg0.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
```

at the beginning of your onTouch function. Like thsi -

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        arg0.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        switch(arg1.getActio){
        }

        return false; 

     }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is to add a touch event and set return value **True**

As you can see here:

```
  someView.setOnTouchListener(object: View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean{
            return true
        }

    })
```

returning True means that the top view is handling the touch and no need to hand over the touch event to other views related.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party but I don't think the accepted solution is very great. Here is a static method that accepts any number of views and disables this event bubbling. This has worked for me 100% of the time for API 17+ (lower untested)

```
public static void disableEventBubbling(View... views){
    for(View view : views){
        if(view != null){
            view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
               @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You can add a case for whatever kind of event you want, or you could get rid of the switch and make the default case the only line inside the touch listener.

Answer (score -2):

Just add a click delegate to the top view background, that will stop the views underneath receiving touches

```
linear_layout_background.Click += delegate
            {
                // Ensures views underneath does not receive touch events
            };
```