# How to create an overlay that blocks touch events to UI below it?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay, android-framelayout

I used a layer of framelayout with a semi-translucent background to create an overlay. 
But this overlay doesn't block touch events to interact with the views below it.
How should create an overlay that blocks all touch events?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable behind view click event Framelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377593/how-to-disable-behind-view-click-event-framelayout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: How to prevent any touch events from being passed from a view to the one underneath it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433387/android-how-to-prevent-any-touch-events-from-being-passed-from-a-view-to-the-on)

Answer (score 37):

If overlay doesn't get touch events, then the events are passed to underlying view, so to block touch events in views below it, make your overlay touchable. `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: This works unless you have the android keyboard open with an edit text focused: the keyboard still intercept the touch events

Comment: I want to pass touch to below screen . https://stackoverflow.com/q/51924911/3496570  plz have a look

Comment: Incredible! Best solution!

Answer (score 9):

Below code has worked for me. I've added `android:clickable="true"` to block touch events to other views below it.

This is an example with a ProgressBar inside the overlay. If you don't want the ProgressBar, you can use the FrameLayout without it.

```
<FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/progress_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:clickable="true">

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:indeterminate="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Improving the Blesson Jose answer, you need set the `android:focusable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"` if you are using View to block the touch.

Answer (score 1):

**put the button on overlay layer.then set that button  android:background="@null" it block touch event of view below it..hope it solve your problem**