# how to make overlay window touchable

Tags: android, overlay, window-managers, system-alert-window

i'm making a feature in my app that display an overlay window with text on the screen, when it appears then i try to touch that window it actually touches behind that window 
i need to make that window touchable , which params should i use ?
here is my code

```
        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater screenNotificationInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layOverTopviewNotification =  screenNotificationInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_notification, null);
        TextView layOverText = (TextView) layOverTopviewNotification.findViewById(R.id.notification_layout);
        layOverText.setText(athkarString[completed]);

        params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(layOverTopviewNotification, params);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an overlay that blocks touch events to UI below it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752924/how-to-create-an-overlay-that-blocks-touch-events-to-ui-below-it)

Comment: i tried what you suggested and it didnt work with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer.

```
windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

inflater = LayoutInflater.from(PlayAthkarService.this);

textView = new TextView(PlayAthkarService.this);
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.floating_window);
textView.setTextSize(20);
textView.setText(athkarString[completed]);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        , WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
}else {
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            , WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
}

params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT ;
params.x = 0;
params.y = 50;

windowManager.addView(textView, params);
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to set textview a touchListener and make textview full screen