# How to disable background touch in FrameLayout?

Tags: android

I have a VideoView and a TextView in FrameLayout, that TextView is showing on VideoView. The TextView is used to show subtitle on movie.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitleTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#41000000"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

1. when I click a word in TextView, the translation of that word will show.
2. and when I touch on VideoView, another works will be done.

But when I click on TextView, the VideoView's touch listener will work too, and this is my problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433387/android-how-to-prevent-any-touch-events-from-being-passed-from-a-view-to-the-on - duplicate question.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `android:clickable=true` add this to your text view

Comment: Thank you so much @Mohammed Atif. That was the right solution! please write it as answer so I can select it as right answer.

Comment: Please refrain from adding chatty material to your posts. The community generally prefers technical writing here. This is not a forum or a chat room. It's worth generally accepting the edits of experienced members of the community unless you feel the technical meaning of your post has been changed. In this case, do not roll back: if you strongly wish to add thanks, please appeal to a moderator, using the flag feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enabling click listener or clickable on any view prevents the touch from passing to its parent views/Underlying Views

In XML add below code to your textview

```
android:clickable=true
```

this should prevent all the touches from passing to underlying videoview.