# Turn screen on and off programatically in android

Tags: android, screen, proximitysensor

I want to turn screen ON and OFF based on the proximity sensor. I am able to turn the screen off. but the code to ON the screen back is not working. Can anyone help me please?
This is the code:`

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if (event.values[0] == 0) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sensor in 0",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
params.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
params.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);


      } else {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sensor in 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

params.screenBrightness = -1;
getWindow().setAttributes(params);
      } 
}`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically

Comment: check this too http://android.okhelp.cz/turn-screen-on-off-android-sample-code/

Comment: I didn't find any useful answer there

Comment: @irfan :Did u get any solution for this ?

Comment: @I-droid : Did you get the soln?

Comment: @Basher51: Yes I'm able to solve this problem. Which I have added as answer. This was also discussed here in my question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22809005/how-to-enable-proximity-sensor-in-android/24175841#24175841`

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31912584/2210080

Answer (score 1):

First I dimmed screen brightness as low as possible and then made all GUI elements unclickable for touch issues. Following is my code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();

    if (event.values[0] == 0) {
        //TODO Store original brightness value
        params.screenBrightness = 0.005f;
        this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT).getParent(),false);
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","NEAR");

    } else {
        //TODO Store original brightness value          
        params.screenBrightness = -1.0f;
        this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);                     
        enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT).getParent(),true);
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","FAR");  
    }       
}
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views), I took reference to disable touch for entire screen's view.

Comment: Why this is so low?? It is one of the cleanest solutions!

Comment: @Usman Clean?  Well for one it doesn't actually turn the screen off!

Answer (score 0):

To turn screen brightness to `on` the value is 1 and to turn it `off` the value is 0.