# How to enable proximity sensor in android

Tags: android, android-sensors, power-management, proximity

I have configured proximeter successfully in my code. Now I want to turn off & on screen programmatically. Code of sensor is working just fine and following method is also getting called.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock screenWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,"screenWakeLock");

    if (event.values[0] == 0) {
        screenWakeLock.acquire();
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","NEAR");
    } else {
        if (screenWakeLock != null) {
               if(screenWakeLock.isHeld())
                  screenWakeLock.release();
               screenWakeLock = null;
        }
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","FAR");  
    }
}
```

My problem is that screen is not getting turn off. I also have added required permission in code. What else could be the reason ???

Comment: @Jonathan why you added java tag in this question?

Comment: The question relates to Java code... perhaps!!!

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android/6757206#6757206

Comment: @JonathanMiles I am android developer, and I am pretty sure, that java tag doesn't suit this question.

Comment: @iago : I'm doing the same what is mentioned in that question.

Comment: Have you tried reducing the brightness, wake lock will only help you to switch on the screen.

Comment: @iago: No i haven't tried. I don't how that thing will work with this. can u guide me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from my understanding `wakelock` is useful to keep screen on. I wasn't successful to turn screen on & off using it.

So, first I dimmed screen brightness as low as possible and then made all GUI elements unclickable. This way I solved my problem.

Following is method:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = this.getWindow().getAttributes();

    if (event.values[0] == 0) {
        //TODO Store original brightness value
        params.screenBrightness = 0.004f;
        this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT).getParent(),false);
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","NEAR");

    } else {
        //TODO Store original brightness value          
        params.screenBrightness = -1.0f;
        this.getWindow().setAttributes(params);                     
        enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.YOUR_MAIN_LAYOUT).getParent(),true);
        Log.e("onSensorChanged","FAR");  
    }       
}
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views), I took reference to disable touch for entire screen's view.

Answer (score 2):

Check the changes submitted for this code, https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-android/compare/6d356fa637ae...7aba481d773f

```
getPowerManager().newWakeLock( 32, "proximity_off");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this shortcut:

```
PowerManager manager = getPowerManager();
WakeLock lock = manager.newWakeLock( 32, "proximity_off");
lock.acquire();
```

The above code doesn't even need the proximity sensor changed events to be listened. `32` is for a hidden `WakeLock` field that is used by the `InCallActivity` of the `Phone` and other such similar applications.

Comment: how do we cancel this?

Comment: `lock.release();` will release the wake lock and stop it.