# How do I disable onTouchEvent listener for custom view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view that I created by extending the `View` class. My custom view overrides the onTouchEvent.
I want to be able to turn the view's ability to listen on and off. I need to do that from within the view. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? Simply calling

```
  setEnabled(false);
```

does not work.

Comment: go through this link..may be it will help u.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting the following

setOnTouchListener(null)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right solution but it works:

```
        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

This blocks other touch related Listeners from receiving the Event, so `onTouchEvent` won't be invoked.

you can use `setOnTouchListener(null)` to go back to your normal state so that your `onTouchEvent` works again.

if you had figured out a better solution i hope that you post it.