# How to disable Touch while video is playing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, youtube-api

I am developing a Toddler(kids) app in which I have shown the YouTube videos thumbnails in a recyclerview  and whenever the user clicks on any of the listed thumbnails that video plays in full screen YouTube intent( and all the videos after that plays in order automatically). I am succeed in doing so. The problem is now I want to disable the touch screen while the video is playing. I thought of making transparent layout and to show this transparent layout as upper layer on YouTube Full screen video intent but i dont know how to attach this layout with Youtube video intent. 
Every kind of help is appreciated.
below is my code:

main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.pc.fkidshell.Main4Activity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/my_thirdtoolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/VideoList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_thirdtoolbar"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

video_row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbnailView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

mainactivity.javaL

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener{
    Toolbar third_toolbar;
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader;
    RecyclerView VideoList;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    List<Drawable> thumbnailViews;
    List<String> VideoId;
    String videoid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
        third_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_thirdtoolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(third_toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.sectitle);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.tblogo);

        thumbnailViews = new ArrayList<>();
        VideoList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.VideoList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        VideoList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter=new VideoListAdapter();
        VideoList.setAdapter(adapter);
        VideoId = new ArrayList<>();
        thumbnailView = new YouTubeThumbnailView(this);
        thumbnailView.initialize("API key", this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {
        thumbnailLoader = youTubeThumbnailLoader;
        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(Main4Activity.this);
        thumbnailLoader.setPlaylist("PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    }

    public void add() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (thumbnailLoader.hasNext())
            thumbnailLoader.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
        thumbnailViews.add(youTubeThumbnailView.getDrawable());
        VideoId.add(s);
        add();
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

    }

    public class VideoListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoListAdapter.MyView>{
        public class MyView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
            ImageView imageView;
            public MyView(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailView);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public VideoListAdapter.MyView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_row, parent, false);
            return new MyView(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(VideoListAdapter.MyView holder, final int position) {
            holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(thumbnailViews.get(position));
            holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    videoid=VideoId.get(position);
                    //startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoid+"&list=PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40")));
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoid+"&index="+position+"&list=PLXRActLQ03oY_6AQb-5EMuKFYQA_fDE40"));
                    intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
                    startActivity(intent);


                   // Intent intenwt=YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntent(Main4Activity.this,VideoId.get(position));
                   // intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return thumbnailViews.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following this will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28429348/7234534

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13943/is-there-a-way-to-disable-touch-temporarily), this is impossible as you cannot override the home button even if it is soft or hard button. However, you can use third party apps like [Untouch](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/95675/191211) which is a very popular one, and can be found in the play store. (Search for Untouch or touch block and it should come up.) You may also check on this [blog](http://www.guidingtech.com/55205/disable-screen-touch-controls-android-toddlers/) that discussed some workaround for your issue. Hope this helps!