# Avoid null pointer exception for touchlistener android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I want to avoid null pointer exception for the following.

I want to disable touch listener for a relative layout.

```
private RelativeLayout    container ;

container.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nahh duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the NPE question even though setting the listener to ``null`` causes one to be thrown. This question is about how to strop android from calling the listener for that particular view.

Comment: `setOnTouchListener(null)` will not cause an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your RelativeLayout so that touch events never triggered  .Use

```
container.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Does it gray-out view ?