# Disable click listener for invisible viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I've a viewgroup which is `View.INVISIBLE` under some circumstances. In this state, i want the viewgroup or it's children views to NOT respond to any click events.

According to the default implementation of `View.INVISIBLE` in android, the child views inside the viewgroup are still clickable even when the viewgroup's visibility is invisible. I know i can set the visibility to `View.GONE` but i don't want the entire viewgroup to be removed.

I tried setting `setClickable` to `true` on the viewgroup but it didn't work and the child views are still responding to clicks. I don't want to iterate through all the views in the viewgroups and disable them individually as this is something that i've to do frequently.

Is there a better solution to prevent all the child views in the viewgroup from receiving click events?

Comment: Try setting a no-op touch listener on the view group.

Comment: child views are still able to receive click events.

Comment: You must return `true` to consume the event.

Comment: you mean  `myViewGroup.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }` ?

Comment: Yes. Please take a look at the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510

Comment: That doesn't work for viewgroup. The other answers in that link point to disabling clicks recursively which i don't want cz i've a lot of views.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try 'setOnClickListener'.

```
viewgroup.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true; // return true can intercept click event go down
        }
    });
```

And you want to receive the viewgroup click event.

```
viewgroup.setOnTouchListener(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setEnabled(false)`?

If that doesn't work, you can set all view children to disabled like this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
    child.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I just saw you didn't want to iterate through all the views, so that's my bad.

Comment: Ahh..ok. No problem. `setEnabled(false)` doesn't work though.