# Disable events in Views Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, touch-event

I am working on an onboarding feature for my android application. I am using tooltips to point at views and I need to disable all touch events to avoid interaction with anything other than the tooltips. I have tried with [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418510/disable-the-touch-events-for-all-the-views), but don't seem to work. I have tried disabling views from both the fragment and the parent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try android:clickable="false" in every view in your XML?
You can probably turn them on again programatically whenever you need to

Comment: Setting isClickable property programatically worked for me. But I do not understand why navView becamose so slow after disabling and enabling it again